# Authentication and policy management of macOS clients

Tags: mac, ldap

Can I manage authentication and policy of macOS clients by LDAP?

Is it possible or there are other solutions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with "policy"?

Comment: @MichaelStröder like a group policy in active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Macs use a special LDAP schema called Open Directory for their authentication and some policy management. There are also ways to have them connect to Active Directory via LDAP.